# Business sale payout mess

Tags: bonus, taxes

The small company I work for is potentially about to be sold (in the UK). I was meant to be getting share options sorted out, but was told that by the time they got around to sorting it out it would have been too close to the sale of the company for me to be able to cash them in. I have been promised the equivalent amount as a bonus upon sale, but this will be taxed as income (as opposed to the tax relief of share options). I will be continuing in my current (or similar) role after the sale.

Whilst the sale figure has not been confirmed, for a sense of scale lets assume the untaxed amount coming to me is in the region of £100k. Does anyone know of any other schemes available that could provide tax relief similar to a share options scheme in this scenario? I'm talking about squeaky clean, legal, above board schemes only here by the way!

Comment: Talk to a UK tax specialist, not a bunch of online users who like helping - this is too important... And hope it all goes well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. There is actually an accountant researching this also. I should probably just leave it to them, but I thought I'd put out some feelers.

Comment: A solicitor specialising in tax, or a tax specialist may be more appropriate, accountants are fairly knowledgable about general tax, but for some things you're best with a specialist.

Comment: What sort of time scale - ideally you would want an EMI scheme but ours took over 9 months to sort out complicated by having to comply with EU law.

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone know of any other schemes available that could provide tax
>   relief

I wouldn't call it a "scheme", but the company could always pay the tax amount instead of you having to do so.

I've received a similar bonus in the past. The bonus was increased by the amount equal to the taxes due.

Comment: Scheme in this case means a HMRC approved one - its a very UK specific tax law term.